# .Net Core 3.0 Cookie Auth. Authorize Attribute always redirecting

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

I've finally got around to converting some .Net Framework projects to Core (3.0). I'm currently just looking at Cookie Authentication and getting a simple example up and running.

I have the claims and login cookie being created with valid data but any controller action with [Authorize] is always redirecting to the login page (Indicating we are not logged in). However, on the Login page, I've output the claims and the IsAuthenticated state and it returns valid data.

LogIn Function

```
 var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "ID"),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "TEST"),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, "Test"),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Surname, "TEST"),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.DateOfBirth, DateTime.Now.ToString("o"), ClaimValueTypes.DateTime)
            };

            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(principal);
```

Example 'Secure Area'

```
        [Authorize()]
        public IActionResult Secure()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Configure Services:

```
        services.AddControllersWithViews();

        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.Name = "TestAuthCookie";
                options.LoginPath = "/Home/Login";
                options.LogoutPath = "/Home/Logout";
            });
```

Configure in Startup.

Comment: Do this happens without customizing `options.Cookie.Name`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per comment: Sometimes people forget to invoke `app.UseAuthentication();` at a very early stage in the middleware pipeline, and as a result, the `HttpContext.User` won't be correctly set.

```
    app.UseAuthentication();   // this line is important
    app.UseAuthorization();
```

Personally, when the authentication doesn't work, I would firstly check whether I have enabled the AuthenticationMiddleware

Comment: Just in case it helps anyone else, the order of UseAuthentication() and UseAuthorization() specifically does seem to matter. I was having problems because I while did add UseAuthentication, I had put it right after authorization, not realizing it mattered.